# Irrationality of $\zeta(\frac{3}{2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta, rationality-testing

Is
$$
\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}
$$
an irrational number?

Comment: Most probably yes, but there is no proof yet.

Comment: Using multiple zeta values, we show the relation,$$\zeta(\frac{3}{2})\zeta(\frac{3}{2})=2\zeta(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})+\zeta(3)$$